# Passing three multi valued parameters to stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure that accepts 3 multi valued parameters and 2 single valued parameters in postgresql.

Previously for 1 multivalued parameter i used the VARIADIC function in postgresql.

Procedure for 1 multi valued paramter-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(
    IN p_fiscal_year integer,
    IN p_program integer,
    VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS TABLE(period character varying, year integer, amt numeric) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
select fiscalperiod.period, fiscalyear.year, SUM(resourcemgmt.estimated_amt) as amt
FROM api_resourcemgmt as resourcemgmt
       INNER JOIN api_fiscalperiod as fiscalperiod ON fiscalperiod.id=resourcemgmt.fiscal_period_id
       INNER JOIN api_fiscalyear as fiscalyear ON fiscalyear.year = fiscalperiod.fiscal_year
       INNER JOIN api_activity as activity ON activity.id = resourcemgmt.activity_id
WHERE fiscalyear.year = p_fiscal_year
AND fiscalperiod.period = ANY($3) --p_month    
AND activity.program_id = p_program 
group by fiscalperiod.period, fiscalyear.year;

END; 
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

But how do i pass 3 multi-valued parameters to a stored procedure in postgresql?

For eg i want a stored procedure to accept inputs and use them in the where clause. The inputs will be as below-

```
select * from stored_procedure(singlevalue1,singlevalue2,multiplevaluefor programs,multiplevaluesforstudents,multiplevalueforgrades);
```

Comment: Use arrays, without `variadic`...